# Protractor clear old inputs while inserting new one

Tags: protractor

I have a form with multiple inputs, problem is when i am inserting new fields protractor clear() inputs from previous fields. And i have no clue why.

My code looks like:

```
it('Populate vehicle data', function() {
    browser.waitForAngular();
    element(by.css('div#datepicking i.glyphicon-calendar')).click();
    element(by.css('div#datepicking button[ng-click="select(\'today\')"]')).click();
    element(by.css('div#datepicking input')).getAttribute('value').then(function(attr) {
        accidentDate = attr;
    });
    element(by.model('case.vehicle.adminData.paintColour')).sendKeys(paintColour);
    element(by.id('form-mileage')).sendKeys(mileage);
    element(by.id('form-mileage-unit')).click().then(function() {
        element(by.cssContainingText('option', lengthUnit)).click();            
    });;
    element(by.model('case.vehicle.adminData.residualValuePercentage')).sendKeys(technicalValue);   
    element(by.id('form-vehicle-condition')).click().then(function() {
        element(by.cssContainingText('option', vehicleCondition)).click();
    });;    
    element(by.id('form-engine-type')).click().then(function() {
        element(by.cssContainingText('option', motorType)).click();
    });;        
    element(by.model('case.vehicle.techData.engineCapacity')).sendKeys(engineCapacity);     
    element(by.model('case.vehicle.techData.enginePower')).sendKeys(enginePower);   
    element(by.id('form-engine-power-unit')).click().then(function() {
        element(by.cssContainingText('option', enginePowerUnit)).click();
    });;                
});
```

Maybe I don't know something about protractor or what ever, but it looks for me it's fine, but it randomly delete all previous inputs when inserting new one.

Comment: Could it be something about how you have your scopes set up? Is it possible that when you change an input value, $digest is called and that recreates the DOM with new controls?

Comment: If i do it manualy it work correctly, so basicly I don't think so:)